# How can I set LIMIT in query in Realm?

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I have done R&D for limit in query with no success. There is one way with which to paginate data in `Realm` with sub list but no success with that. It shows duplicate value in it.

Here is what I attempted for pagination.

```
 RealmResults<Person> mPersonData=RealmUtils.getAllPersonWithTagsDescending(); 
    if (mPersonData != null) { 
    int startPos=getAllPerson.size()-1; 
    int endPos=mPersonData.size()-1; 
    List<Person> newPersonData=mPersonData.subList(startPos,endPos);   
    getAllPerson.addAll(newPersonData); 
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you need the limit  query ?

Comment: @param he probably doesn't need a LIMIT query because of how Realm works. He just doesn't seem to know it yet.

Comment: Hi @param I need to sync data from API and Database so I have face problem about data duplication while load more data from API.

Comment: You should probably specify your transaction then. You'll need the rank parameter for consistent results that you would set in your transaction, just like [this example](https://github.com/Zhuinden/rx-realm-recyclerview-experiment/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/rxrealm/path/cat/CatPersister.java#L15-L30)

Comment: there is no relationship between paginate  and  duplicatation

Comment: @param there is if you do an unordered `findAll()` multiple times and then randomly try to get a `subList` of it randomly (`findAll()` does not guarantee order) - of course, if he just threw the `RealmResults<T>` into the `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` then he would not need to do any manual `notifyDataSetChanged()` when new data is committed to the Realm.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce but  findAll will not return duplicate value order could be changed when you use randomly .

Comment: @param well technically the order can change if you also delete from the results.

Comment: @PyusAndroid use this link hope it will help you
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/

Comment: @param if there's one thing for sure, he should use the official `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` from https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters instead of the hack in the article made for 0.82.1

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Will update you on this after implement which you suggested to me Thanks for Help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `limit` from Realm 5.6.0+. It looks like this.

```
val myDataList = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    .where(MyData::class.java)
    .limit(10)
    .findAll()
```

Look [this document](https://realm.io/docs/java/5.6.0/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#limit-long-)

Answer (score 19):

There is no reason to use pagination with Realm if you use `RealmResults<T>` directly, because the elements in `RealmResults` are lazy evaluated, and aren't in memory until you call `.get(i)`.

Meaning, the query doesn't execute and evaluate an element until you directly index it. Which means, they aren't in memory. The `RealmResults<T>` list doesn't actually *contain* the elements, it just knows how to find them.

As such, there is no `LIMIT` in Realm.

Please note that if I remember correctly, reevaluating two `RealmResults` that are not returned by `findAllSorted` can have different ordering (if deletions occur). If the order must be the same no matter what, then consider a `rank` property, and order by `findAllSorted("rank", Sort.ASCENDING)`.

If you **really** want pagination, you should have the rank parameters, and then you can create a query like

```
realm.where(SomeClass.class)
     .greaterThanOrEqualTo("rank", pageSize*pageIndex + 0)
     .lessThan(SomeClassFields.RANK, pageSize*pageIndex + pageSize)
     .findAllSorted(SomeClassFields.RANK, Sort.ASCENDING);
```

---

Also, you should consider using [`RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.java) instead from [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters):

```
compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0' // for Realm 0.89.0 to Realm 2.3.0
```

or

```
compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.0' // for Realm 3.0.0+
```

or

```
compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:3.0.0' // for Realm 5.0.0+
```

The `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` handles "loading the new data" for you, you don't have to do anything to make it work beyond setting the initial `RealmResults`.

---

---

I'll actually have to change this answer once there is proper integration with the Paging Architecture Component, who knew? I have an experiment up with it [**here**](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-helpers/tree/4b83911b20304355e95870e51a1743bc141a36fd/realm-pagination/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/realmpagination) and you can see if it works for you.

Comment: Since then, there is LIMIT, but there is no OFFSET.

Answer (score 4):

As @EpicPandaForce said, you can use `lessThan()`and `greaterThan()` to set the limit, but realm have `between()` method, check: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#chaining-queries

**Example :**

Just get items with limit 50 :

```
static int LIMIT = 50;
final RealmResults<Item> resultsFilter = realm.where(Item.class)
                .between("id", 0, LIMIT)
                .findAllSorted("id", Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Or when I want to get last 10 items:

```
static int LIMIT = 10;
final RealmResults<Item> resultsAll = realm.where(Item.class).findAll();
final RealmResults<Item> resultsFilter = realm.where(Item.class)
                .between("id", resultsAll.size() - LIMIT, resultsAll.size())
                .findAllSorted("id", Sort.DESCENDING);
```

Comment: This will only work correctly as long as you have objects for all id values starting with 1 (or 0). As soon as you start deleting objects, this will break / result in less items than expected.

Answer (score 1):

**Now limit is supporting**

**I did that using limit method,** **You should use latest version**         `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.8.0"`

```
RealmResults<YourPOJOClass> realmResults = mRealm.where(YourPOJOClass.class).sort("createdTime").limit(10).findAll();
//here this record will be sorted by ascending order using schema name "createdTime" 
//this will return the 10 rows only.
```

`

Comment: I add it but i am not able to use limit() in realm.i used implementation 'io.realm:realm-android:0.81.1' this plug in app level build.gradle file