# How to get first n rows in-memory from realm

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list, realm-java

I want to get only first 10 or possibly n rows in-memory as java list using **copyFromRealm** method. Consider like this:

```
RealmResults<RecentViewItem> results = realm.where(RecentViewItem.class).findAllSorted("updatedAt", Sort.DESCENDING);
// This will load all rows in-memory list
List<RecentViewItem> list = realm.copyFromRealm(results);

// But I want only first n rows without running any loop.
```

**UPDATE:**
Since RealmResult extends AbstractList -

```
RealmResults<RecentViewItem> results =
                realm.where(RecentViewItem.class)
                        .findAllSorted("updatedAt", Sort.DESCENDING);
List<RecentViewItem> temp = results.subList(0, maxNoRecentViewItem);   // Still list of RealmProxyObject
List<RecentViewItem> list = realm.copyFromRealm(temp);   // List of RecentViewItem Object
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set LIMIT in query in Realm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38873402/how-can-i-set-limit-in-query-in-realm)

Comment: With normal use, there is also no reason to call `copyFromRealm()`. The only time it makes sense with proper Realm usage is when you want to send a managed object through something that relies on reading fields directly - basically, if you send an object as `@Body` with Retrofit using a `GsonAdapterFactory`. Otherwise, `copyFromRealm()` is typically a mis-use of Realm API.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Sorry I don't agree that copyFromRealm() is a mis-use or discouraged. Sometimes you don't need Realm Managed Object (RealmProxyObject) all the time or you want few rows in-memory.

Comment: Only other cases I can imagine is reordering, and creating modifiable copies you'd like to save back later.