# Limit recyclerview items to only 10 without paginating with filter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I am using Recycler View with 283 items with an ordinary TextView to filter the list.

I want to display only 10 records all the time.

I can't use getCount (or GetItemCount) because when I filter the list it gives me IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions, is there any other way to do this?

```
public class RealmAutoCompleteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RealmAutoCompleteAdapter.ProductViewHolder>  {
Realm realm;

RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<FieldsItem>> realmChangeListener;
RealmResults<FieldsItem> items;
String searchTerm;

public RealmAutoCompleteAdapter(Realm realm, RealmResults<FieldsItem> items) {
    this.realm = realm;
    this.realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<FieldsItem>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<FieldsItem> results) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    this.items = items;
    items.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
}

@Override
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ProductViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_row, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
    FieldsItem item = items.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
}

public void updateInput(String input) {
    this.searchTerm = input;
    if(items != null && items.isValid()) {
        items.removeAllChangeListeners();
    }
    RealmQuery<FieldsItem> query = realm.where(FieldsItem.class);
    if(searchTerm != null && !"".equals(searchTerm)) {
        query = query.contains("title", searchTerm, Case.INSENSITIVE);
    }
    items = query.findAll();
    items.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(items == null || !items.isValid()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return items.size();
}

static class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextViewWithFont title;
    ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextViewWithFont)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Is it design requirement that you only load in 10 items at a time?  That seems unnecessary, and if not possible duplicate:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38873402/how-can-i-set-limit-in-query-in-realm

Answer (score 12):

You could do:

```
return Math.min(items.size(), 10);
```

Comment: is it possible to do this in Activity rather than the adapter? like setting the adapter to only show 10 items?

Comment: Well the adapter decides this based on what you return in `getItemCount()`.

Comment: Thanks, nice solution.

Comment: This should be marked as answer.