# Is realm database have a storage limit for mobile application?

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-database

I am creating an android application and its also working offline mode for offline storage i  used **Realm Database**.

**What i want to do**

first i want check the database size before insert any data
is realm provide facility/code for checking database size/limit ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit on storing data but as Mobile devices are memory sensitive so we should not save much data.

Although there is no limit on storing data by realm but there is limit in saving single String or byte[] of max `16MB` (AFIK).

> first i want check the database size before insert any data is realm
>   provide facility/code for checking database size/limit ?

You just have to check device memory if you want a check.

Comment: Hi ,
Thanks for your quick reply , Would be appreciated if you could share the related link for the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38873402/how-can-i-set-limit-in-query-in-realm You can conclude analysis from this question too

Comment: Thanks for sharing all  link its really helpful for me.